# Book recommendation to study $L^p$ spaces which deal with vector-valued functions.

Tags: functional-analysis

When I study the Dirac equation, which solution is vector-valued, I realized that I have no knowledges about $L^p$-theory which is dealing with vector-valued function. (like extended version of Holder's or Young's convolution inequality, etc.) Its general function space is already known as *Lebesgue-Bochner space* whose functions map from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to some Banach space, but my interest is only $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n\ge 2$ not general Banach spaces.

Is there any book to study/investigate that function spaces?

Comment: If your target space is finite-dimensional, then you have two options: do things component wise so you end up with a direct sum of $n$ copies of the usual Lebesgue space. Or, specialize the Banach space stuff to finite-dimensions; in reality, much of the basic theory goes through without any real difficulty/real simplification. Lang, Amann Escher talk about Banach-valued integration, but I doubt you’re going to find any text specifically focused on integration theory when the target space is not one-dimensional yet finite-dimensional…

Comment: Because like I mentioned, the theory is either an almost direct extension of the one-dimensional case or a trivial restriction of the general Banach space theory to finite-dimensions (which like I said doesn’t simplify things for much of the basic theory). This is that sort of weird middle ground.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try it analogously and then, if I need it, read the books you and @NewB mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the classical text "Vector measures" by J.Diestel and J.J Uhl. Second chapter introduces the reader to Bochner integrals and vector valued $L^p$ spaces and their duals and generalization of many classical results of integration theory.